# Create Structuring Element for Image Morphology Python

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, image-morphology

I am working with morphological operations.I have a Matlab script which generate the Structuring Element using the function `strel('form', w)` where the **form** of the SE can be a **line**, **disk**, **diamond**, **square**, or other form (I need at least the function to be able to generate this 4 forms), and **w** is the size of the matrix (w*w) generated for the SE.
I want to know if there is a function in Python similar to Matlab "strel()" that automatically generates the Structuring Element.
I´ve search for this kind of function, but none of them seems to be able to generate all this 4 different Structuring Element forms.

Answer (score 3):

[Scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html) has functions to generate square, rectangle, disk, diamond, octagon and star shaped structuring elements.

They are separate functions, not a single function, but I can’t imagine that being a problem.

Call them as `skimage.morphology.<shape>()`. See [this documentation page](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/numpy_operations/plot_structuring_elements.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-numpy-operations-plot-structuring-elements-py) for demos.

Horizontal and vertical lines are rectangle shapes, of course. Lines at arbitrary angles can be generated by drawing a line in an all-zeros array with [skimage.draw.line](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the built-in OpenCV functions appear to provide [only rectangles, ellipses, and crosses.](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html#Structuring_Element) So you'll have to write your own function for that.

Alternatively, you could try to get MATLAB and python to interact with each other, and [call MATLAB from python.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html) Refer to the various documentation pages on how to do this:

- [Installing MATLAB engine](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)
- [Start / Stop MATLAB engine in Python](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/start-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)
- [Call functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html)